# Django Permission classe gets called twice

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i'm facing an odd problem in my project. I have created a simple custom permission class to understand how the system works.

```
class CustomPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):

        print("something")

        return True
```

When I try add this permission to an APIVIew in the terminal "something" prints twice.
Is it normal for a view to check permission two times for the same request?

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with this issue. Turns out the API was being called twice. Because I was calling the API in my browser, DRF called an OPTIONS request after the GET request. By simply passing `&format=json` only GET was called.